# if we click on Review Tap then should be show only Review but they show also search_result_are_available how to solve

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
isData && _availableroom
    ? Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Container(
              child: Column(
            children: _roomoptions(),
          )),
        ],
      )
    : isData && _hotelDetail && !_hotelReviews
        ? hotelDetailModel != null
            ? Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 10.0, right: 10, top: 5),
                child: Container(
                    child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      _locations(),
                      hotelDetailModel.result.descriptions.toString() !=
                                  "null" &&
                              hotelDetailModel.result.descriptions
                                      .toString() !=
                                  ""
                          ? SizedBox(height: 20)
                          : Container(),
                      hotelDetailModel.result.descriptions.toString() !=
                                  "null" &&
                              hotelDetailModel.result.descriptions
                                      .toString() !=
                                  ""
                          ? Padding(
                              padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                              child: titleView(
                                  localText("About the Hotel", context),
                                  ""))
                          : Container(),
                      SizedBox(height: 5),
                      aboutHotel(),
                      SizedBox(height: 15),
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          child: titleView(
                              localText("Hotel Policy", context), "")),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 108,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  TextWidget(
                                    text: localText(
                                            "check_in_time", context) +
                                        " ",
                                    fontfamily: "Inter",
                                    color: Color(0xff64788b),
                                  ),
                                  Spacer(),
                                  Container(
                                    child: TextWidget(
                                      text: ":",
                                      fontfamily: "Inter",
                                      color: Color(0xff64788b),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            if (firstdate.toString() != "null")
                              Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0),
                                child: TextWidget(
                                  text: " $firstdate " ?? "",
                                  fontfamily: "Inter",
                                  color: Color(0xff64788b),
                                ),
                              ),
                            if (hotelDetailModel.result.info.checkin
                                    .toString() !=
                                "null")
                              TextWidget(
                                text:
                                    "${hotelDetailModel.result.info.checkin}" ??
                                        "",
                                fontfamily: "Inter",
                                color: Color(0xff64788b),
                              ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 110,
                              child: TextWidget(
                                text: localText(
                                        "check_out_time", context) +
                                    " :",
                                fontfamily: "Inter",
                                color: Color(0xff64788b),
                              ),
                            ),
                            if (seconddate.toString() != "null")
                              TextWidget(
                                text: " $seconddate " ?? "",
                                fontfamily: "Inter",
                                color: Color(0xff64788b),
                              ),
                            if (hotelDetailModel.result.info.checkout
                                    .toString() !=
                                "null")
                              TextWidget(
                                text:
                                    "${hotelDetailModel.result.info.checkout}" ??
                                        "",
                                fontfamily: "Inter",
                                color: Color(0xff64788b),
                              ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      if (listRooms[0]
                                  .roomTypes[0]
                                  .additionalInfo
                                  .toString() !=
                              "null" &&
                          listRooms[0]
                                  .roomTypes[0]
                                  .additionalInfo
                                  .toString() !=
                              "")
                        SizedBox(height: 15),
                      if (listRooms[0]
                                  .roomTypes[0]
                                  .additionalInfo
                                  .toString() !=
                              "null" &&
                          listRooms[0]
                                  .roomTypes[0]
                                  .additionalInfo
                                  .toString() !=
                              "")
                        Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                            child: titleView(
                                localText(
                                    "Important Information", context),
                                "")),
                      if (listRooms[0]
                                  .roomTypes[0]
                                  .additionalInfo
                                  .toString() !=
                              "null" &&
                          listRooms[0]
                                  .roomTypes[0]
                                  .additionalInfo
                                  .toString() !=
                              "")
                        SizedBox(height: 5),

                      impoHotel(),
                      if (hotelDetailModel.result.facilities.length > 0)
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                      if (hotelDetailModel.result.facilities.length > 0)
                        Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                            child: titleView(
                                localText("Facilities", context), "")),
                      if (hotelDetailModel.result.facilities.length > 0)
                        SizedBox(height: 2),
                      if (hotelDetailModel.result.facilities.length > 0)
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          child: Container(
                              child: Column(
                            children: _faci(),
                          )),
                        ),
                      
                      SizedBox(height: 10)
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
              )
            : Container()
        : Container(
            child: Center(
                child: TextWidget(
              text: localText("search_result_are_available", context),
              size: 18,
            )),
          ),
_hotelReviews && !_hotelDetail && !_availableroom
    ? _hotelReviewTap()
    : Container()
```

Comment: Can you describe your code and issue? More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `_hotelReviews` flag to the `search_result_are_available`. It's going to be the following snippet:

```dart
      : _hotelReviews ?
        ? Container()
        : Container(
            child: Center(
                child: TextWidget(
              text: localText("search_result_are_available", context),
              size: 18,
            )),
          ),
```